# Jquery Show and hide is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a shopify website, What I am trying to achieve is, When you hover over menus on the website, Currently it is showing two products with the name (Most Popular Product) there are two different products, So what I am trying is hide Demo product on hover over first menu title and show Demoproduct2 and hide Demo product2 on hover over second menu title and show Demoproduct

I have Given them different ids also

```
Latest Arrivals:#tabbs0
Editors Picks:#tabbs5
```

```
DemoProduct:menuproductone
Demoproduct2:menuproducttwo
```

This is my website url: https://amused-dev.myshopify.com/

So far I have tried this

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("a#tabbs0").hover(function() {
    jQuery('div#menuproductone').show();
  }, function() {
    jQuery('div#menuproducttwo').hide();
  });

  jQuery("a#tabbs5").hover(function() {
    jQuery('div#menuproducttwo').show();
  }, function() {
    jQuery('div#menuproductone').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: Can you add the corresponding html to the snippet please?

Comment: So what is your problem?

Comment: <a href="#" class="nav-link" id="tabbs0">
            Latest Arrivals
          </a>

Comment: It is working only once, when i hover next time again on any of the menu title it is showing both the products

Comment: Start by updating your menu HTML as you have duplicate ids. `document.querySelectorAll('#menuproductone')` returns 6 items when it should only be 1. Ids are meant to be unique.

Comment: It is working fine, but on other remaning menu titles it should show the two products

Comment: Please ensure all relevant code/html is *in the question itself* - your shopify link will no doubt change (if it hasn't already)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `show()` and `hide()` functions together.

You are using two functions inside each `hover` event.

1. The first function binds to `mouseenter` event
2. The second function binds to `mouseleave` event

Avoid that and you are good to go.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("a#tabbs0").hover(function() {
    jQuery('div#menuproductone').show();
    jQuery('div#menuproducttwo').hide();
  });

  jQuery("a#tabbs5").hover(function() {
    jQuery('div#menuproducttwo').show();
    jQuery('div#menuproductone').hide();
  });
});
```